# Understanding a basic modular patterns private and public functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just looking at the code of a simple demonstration of modular pattern, have a look :

```
// Global module
var myModule = (function ( jQ, _ ) {

    function privateMethod1(){
        jQ(".container").html("test");
    }

    function privateMethod2(){
      console.log( _.min([10, 5, 100, 2, 1000]) );
    }

    return{
        publicMethod: function(){
            privateMethod1();
        }
    };

// Pull in jQuery and Underscore
})( jQuery, _ );

myModule.publicMethod();
```

The code is pretty straightforward, what I don't understand is what's the need for a `publicMethod`? Why are `privateMethod1` and `privateMethod2` inaccessible?  I understand that `privateMethod1` and `privateMethod2` are classic js functions and `publicMethod` is more of a variable assigned to hold a function.

Comment: `publicMethod` is a method accessible from the outside. If you don't need it, remove it.

Comment: `privateMethod1` appear "accessible" at `publicMethod` , though not appear can be altered using existing `js` ?  _"what i don't understand is whats the need for a publicMethod ?"_ `publicMethod` appear to call `privateMethod1` ?

Comment: why are privateMethod1 and privateMethod2 inaccessible ? thats my question .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Not certain if interpret _"inaccessible"_ correctly ? `privateMethod1` can be called with `myModule.publicMethod();` ? What is expected result ?

Answer (score 2):

`privateMethod1()` and `privateMethod2()` are local functions declared inside the module function wrapper.  As such, they are only visible and callable from within that function wrapper.  They can't be reached from outside the module wrapper.

This is the same as a local variable inside a function.

```
function someFunc() {
    // a function declared inside another function is ONLY available
    // inside that function
    function localFunc() {
        // do something
    }

    // this is just like a local variable which is only available within
    // the scope of the function itself
    var myVariable = 2;
}

// can't call localFunc here - this will be an error
// because it is defined in a different scope and not available here
localFunc();
```

Private methods can be useful when you want to create functions or methods that the public methods can use, but you do not want outside callers to be able to also call or use those functions/methods.

Private variables can be used to store state that the public methods or private methods want to reference, but you don't want the outside callers to have access to or be able to mess with.